# Is there a way to fetch artifacts from a Bazel remote cache without running a build?

Tags: bazel

I have a Bazel iOS project. When I run `bazel build //foo/bar:wiz`, Bazel will try to fetch artifacts from the configured remote cache. If those artifacts don't exist, Bazel will build the artifacts locally.

I am interested in pre-fetching remote artifacts that exist on the remote cache *without* triggering a build. Fetching the remote artifacts is more lightweight than compiling. If this command existed, potentially I could run it in the background after pulling new changes from the remote repository as a way of pre-warming my local Bazel artifact cache.

I see the [`bazel fetch` command](https://bazel.build/run/build#fetching-external-dependencies) but this command seems to only load external dependencies. Based on a local test and [this documentation](https://bazel.build/external/overview), external dependencies are different than remote cache artifacts.

Is there a Bazel command for fetching artifacts from the remote cache without building artifacts locally?

Comment: `bazel build --nobuild`?

Comment: In a local test `bazel build --nobuild` does not seem to fetch artifacts from the remote cache.